# Number to words c++

Tags: c++, string, numbers

This is a program to print number(numeric) in English
example 1 to "One"
I have used 2 string of arrays to print, Number in English.
1st for 1 to 20.
2nd for 10,20,30...90.
3rd string for hundred
Please assist me to print number after 20 like 21 which include 2 string from different arrays and return them from a function as one.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
string convert(int x);
int main()
{
    int no;
    string no_in_eng;
    cout << "Enter a number\n";
    cin >> no;
    no_in_eng = convert(no);
    cout << no_in_eng << " Ruppess";
    return 0;
}
string convert(int x)
{  // array of string from 1 to 20
    string ones[] = { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six",
                      "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten",
                      "Eleven", "Twevle", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen",
                      "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Ninteen", "Twenty" };

    string hun = "Hundred";

//array of string for (20,30,40...90)
    string tens[] = { "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty"              ,
                      "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninty" };

    {
        if (x <= 0)
            //if not used surprisingly 0 will print ninty
            return "zero or negative";

        else if (x < 21)
            return *(ones + x - 1);

        else if (x < 99)
        {
            //Need help with two digit number
            return 0;
        }
        else if (x < 999)
        {
            //need help with 3 digit number
            return 0;
        }
        else
            cout << "wrong number choice";
    }
}
```

Comment: Indentation and braces would  help

Comment: Need help to print 2 string from different arrays in one return statement

Comment: _"Please assist me ..."_ That's not how to ask valid questions here. _"Need help"_ neither.

Comment: Start by writing these functions: `unsigned int tens(unsigned int n);` and `unsigned int units(unsigned int n);` which return tens and units, assuming that `0<=n<=99`. Then extend `tens` so that it works with larger numbers.

Comment: @Maddy Maybe you can [reword your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47740858/edit) and provide a [MCVE] pointing out what's the problem with your code?

Comment: if there are 2 arrray 
arr[1] with string "user";
arr[2] with string "042";
print arr 1+2 so it print user042 and return it to function as string

Comment: @Maddy Again: **[Edit]** additional information into your question, rather than responding in comments please! And if you're at it, fix that horrible code formatting also.

Comment: This is a "How would you do this by hand?" type question, so how would you do this if someone gave you a pencil and a piece of paper?  Do it on paper and write down all the steps you needed to perform. Turn the steps into a logic diagram to see if you've missed anything and correct the diagram until you know you your steps are sound and then translate the diagram into code.

Comment: That is not my question I did make a diagram and structure of how to do it

Comment: The question is  if there are 2 array 
     arr[1] with string "user";
     arr[2] with string "042";
     print arr 1+2 so it print user042 and return it to function as string

Comment: combine 2 string  from 2 different arrays together so they form one string and return

Comment: @user4581301 using multidimensional can help?

Comment: `*(ones + x - 1)` --> `ones[x-1]`. Avoid pointer arithmetic when you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write a number, say 3215, out yourself, you don't go "is it less than 10? No. Is it less than a hundred? No...".
You go "Is it more than 1000? Yes, and the thousands are three. What are the hundreds? Two...".

Reverse your logic in the program, too:

- If the number is greater than 999, print the thousands, and get the remainder when dividing by one thousand.
- If the remainder is greater than 99, print the hundreds, and get the remainder when dividing by one hundred.
- And so on.

This is an exercise in using the `/` and `%` operators, so do that.

Comment: Thank you, i understand now but can we return two address together like I did in one's case/

Comment: @Maddy You're not returning *any* addresses, so I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I am returning a pointer to a function, which will point to specific (string in the array)-1  for below 21 number. 1 to 20, but in case of above 20.  For example 21 "twenty"+" one" has to be printed.How to do that.

Comment: @Maddy No, you're not. You're return a `string`, `ones[x-1]` (although you wrote it using pointer arithmetic). It's not a pointer, and absolutely not a pointer to a function.